# capistrano 3 + rvm1-capistrano3 rails 4.1 secrets.yml environmental variables issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, capistrano, capistrano3, rvm-capistrano

I have been deploying rails 4.1 application with capistrano 3. it has been working fine. but 
when i tried to do rake tasks (uncommenting require 'capistrano/rails/assets'). i get this error

```
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:

  * development - set it to false
  * test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test environment)
  * production - set it to true

rake aborted!
ArgumentError: Missing required arguments: google_storage_access_key_id, google_storage_secret_access_key
/home/deploy/yelo/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/fog-core-1.24.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:237:in `validate_options'
/home/deploy/yelo/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/fog-core-1.24.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:261:in `handle_settings'
/home/deploy/yelo/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/fog-core-1.24.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:98:in `new'
/home/deploy/yelo/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/fog-core-1.24.0/lib/fog/storage.rb:26:in `new'
/home/deploy/yelo/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:83:in `eager_load_fog'
/home/deploy/yelo/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:96:in `fog_credentials='
/home/deploy/yelo/releases/20140910131617/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:8:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/deploy/yelo/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:118:in `configure'
/home/deploy/yelo/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave.rb:14:in `configure'
/home/deploy/yelo/releases/20140910131617/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deploy/yelo/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/home/deploy/yelo/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
```

the config.eager_load is set to true.  the thing with google_storage_access_key_id the keys are initialized inside a initializer with values config.secrets.yml

```
require 'fog'
require 'rails'
require 'carrierwave'

CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.root = Rails.root.join('tmp')
  config.cache_dir = 'carrierwave'
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider                         => 'Google',
    :google_storage_access_key_id     => Rails.application.secrets.storage_access_key,
    :google_storage_secret_access_key => Rails.application.secrets.storage_access_secret
  }
  config.fog_directory = 'yelostore'

end
```

config.secrets.yml

```
  storage_access_key: <%= ENV['STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY']%>
  storage_access_secret: <%= ENV['STORAGE_ACCESS_SECRET']%>
```

i stored my environmental variables in /etc/profile.

there issues arise only if i do some rake or execute tasks.
if i removed the initializer file i get another error 
Devise.secret_key was not set. Please add the following to your Devise initializer:

config.secret_key = '6b88a299ed1361b5c0275e.....'

this is essentiall because of secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %> not getting loaded at that point.

Finally i can run all tasks i go to the root path. only while doing it through capistarno these errors arise. as capistarno not getting the config.scecrets env variables which is stored in /etc/profile

Answer (score 0):

capistrano seems like to look into environmental variables from /etc/environment rather than shell so bashrc or profile didnt't work.

The config.eager_load issue was solved after i upgraded to capistrano 3.0rc to 3.2

Comment: Sort of. The error is not occurring in Capistrano per se, it's in your rails environment. Capistrano creates processes that load your rails environment and since your rails environment is misconfigured, the error is being thrown. Second, bashrc is the configuration file for the shell. Rails is not running from the shell, it's running through nginx (or whatever you're using). So the vars in bashrc aren't loaded. In linux like Ubuntu, the place to put envars for things that run sans the shell is in /etc/environment. You will need sudo to edit that file, and reboot after changing it.

Comment: @IAmNaN is right - nginx doesn't load shell configuration files. I am not sure, however, whether the profile file would work. I'd rather use [capistrano-secrets-yml](https://github.com/capistrano-plugins/capistrano-secrets-yml) to copy over and symlink the production settings from the local secrets.yml file.

Comment: Nice @Nick! I'll start using that in my projects.

Answer (score 0):

The Error has nothing to do with the secret_key_base.
In the file config/initializers/devise.rb add the config.secret_key='6b88...' within the setup block:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.secret_key = '6b88a299ed1361b5c0275e...'
  ...
end
```