# rails4 deployment logs out all users

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, devise, thin, capistrano3

got some strange behavior since quite a while. After deployment (with capistarano) all users need to sign in again!

happens in several apps, since Rails 4.x .. here some versions:

- **Rails**: 4.2.5 / 4.2.6
- **Devise**: 3.5.3 / 3.5.6 / 4.2.0
- **Capistrano**: 3.4.0
- **Ruby**: 2.2.1 / 2.3.0
- Web-Server: **nginx**
- App-Server: **thin** (1.6.4 / 1.7.0)

this is really annoying, especially because zero-downtime-deployment makes no sence anymore and remember-me doesn't work at all

models/user

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ..
  devise  :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, 
          :validatable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :omniauthable, :invitable, 
          :omniauth_providers => CONFIG[:devise_provider]
  ..
end
```

initializers/devise

```
Devise.setup do |config|

  config.secret_key = 'xxx-key-xxx'

  config.mailer_sender = CONFIG[:mail_system]

  config.mailer = 'AccountMailer'

  require 'devise/orm/active_record'

  config.case_insensitive_keys = [:email]

  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [:email]

  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]

  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10

  config.invite_for = 0

  config.reconfirmable = true

  config.expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out = true

  config.password_length = CONFIG[:password_min_length]..CONFIG[:password_max_length]

  config.timeout_in = 6.hours

  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours

  config.sign_out_via = :delete

  config.omniauth :facebook,      CONFIG[:facebook_id], CONFIG[:facebook_secret], {info_fields: 'email, first_name, last_name, gender', image_size: "large"}
  config.omniauth :google_oauth2, CONFIG[:google_id],   CONFIG[:google_secret], {
    skip_jwt: true,
    scope: "email, profile, plus.me",
    # prompt: "select_account",
    image_aspect_ratio: "square",
    image_size: 200
  }

end
```

Most of the apps are running in production, so I don't touch the database while deployment (except for migrations).
Also happens in apps without devise_invitable, so this also don't causes it.

.. thanks for any help! ..

also posted as [devise #4277](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/4277)

Comment: How is your `config/secrets.yml` configured? While it isn't the only way this can happen, if your production secret changes on each deploy, all the sessions would expire.

Comment: in 2 of the apps is hardcoded in deploy.rb so can't change .. but will check again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### solved it!

The problem was caused by the only thing I didn't mention: `rvm`or better `rvm1-capistrano3`which completely ignores `~/.bachrc`, `~/.profile` and so on.

**I had to put `secret_key_base` in `/etc/environment` now it works as expected.**

*Till now `secret_key_base` was just a huge pain in the ass for me, because all documented usage didn't work and I had to put secret_key_base in `:default_env` and also inject it in some monit scripts.  ie: to restart `sidekiq` or `thin` (therefore it was hardcoded in `deploy.rb`)*

Thanks to surendar, his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25768426/1470996) on [capistrano 3 + rvm1-capistrano3 rails 4.1 secrets.yml environmental variables issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766976/capistrano-3-rvm1-capistrano3-rails-4-1-secrets-yml-environmental-variables-is) was the solution.

It still don't seems to be the best solution *(but it works)*, so I'll stay open for better solutions.